# How to get list of nodes and containers for finished job on YARN via console?

Tags: hadoop-yarn

There is an application which triggers by oozie every 5 min on YARN. And **I need to know containers and nodes on which the application containers were run at some point of time** (a job id is known).
I found the following commands to get such information:

```
$ yarn applicationattempt -list {{ APPLICATION_ID }} // get ApplicationAttempt_Id
$ yarn container -list {{ ApplicationAttempt_Id }}
```

The last command returns a list of containers with needed information about nodes. **But that works only for job in running state**, and for the completed job it returns nothing.

*How to get such information about nodes and containers of the finished job? 
And is it possible to do that by yarn command via the console?*

Thanks,